# What's the difference between accessing a document field via .value/.values or not in painless script?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Suppose that i have a doc mapping field like below

```
{
    "template": {
        "mappings":{
            "template":{
                "properties": {
                    "sth": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The field sth is the type of array.

I want to check whether the field sth contains a value or not, so i write painless script like `doc['sth'].values.contains((long)1)`

It works. However, if i write `doc['sth'].contains((long)1)`, accessing the field not via `.values`, it also can works.

I've also tried some instance method like `isEmpty()`, `size()`, both can work whether via `.values` or not.

So, what's the difference between accessing a document field via .value/.values or not in painless script? What does painless do under the hood?